# How to access json response that have the following format

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I get a response like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        "http:\/\/www.domain.com.br\/anunciantes\/jorgediaz.y.com.r\/26\/img1.jpg",
        "http:\/\/www.domain.com.br\/anunciantes\/jorgediaz.t.com.r\/26\/img2.jpg"
    ]
}
```

I have tried:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/imovel/recuperar_fotos",
         datatype: 'JSON',
         contentType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
                  var i = 0;
               while(i < 3)
               {
                   alert(data[i]);
                   i++;
            }

        }
    });
```

and also data[0][i] doesn't work.

Comment: did you try to do `data.data[i]` ?

Comment: That's right, `data` is an object with a key also named `data`, so you access the array using `data.data`

Comment: Worked. Excuse-me for the simple question, I would try more but I want show a personal project for a person and I am short on time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are receiving an *object* that has a *data* property that is an *array*. Therefore you could iterate over response.data (or data.data, following your code naming).

Here you have 3 ways to iterate over an array (and avoid the while loop)

Using array's forEach method

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/imovel/recuperar_fotos",
  datatype: 'JSON',
  contentType: 'JSON',
  success: function (response) {
    var photos = response.data;
    photos.forEach(function(photo) {
      console.log(photo);
    })
  }
});
```

Using the for ... in

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/imovel/recuperar_fotos",
  datatype: 'JSON',
  contentType: 'JSON',
  success: function (response) {
    var photos = response.data;
    for (var i in photos) {
      console.log(photos[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Using the classig for loop

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/imovel/recuperar_fotos",
  datatype: 'JSON',
  contentType: 'JSON',
  success: function (response) {
    var photos = response.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
      console.log(photos[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/imovel/recuperar_fotos",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(res) {
        for (i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
            alert(res.data[i]);
        }
    }
});
```